After upgrading Ubuntu "Oh no! Something went wrong"
Ubuntu in Oracle VM got upgraded and ran into error: A problem has occurred and system can't recover, please contact system administrator.
I have attached the photo of it.

I tried all the steps in the answer of previously asked question After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong".
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt remove gnome-session gnome gnome-shell
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot

but could not solve it. After sudo reboot in the end it still says the same.

The commands you list performing are in the INCORRECT order; which differs to the question you tagged... I suggest re-following the link you provided correctly... sudo apt update just updates software lists, the following sudo apt upgrade THUS knows what is available.. your executing the upgrade first will mean it did nothing... as you'd not yet updated software lists using apt update...  I'd also use apt full-upgrade and not just apt upgrade.  FYI:  If you'd made a change to your system (you don't mention) in the session before your problem, that won't be fixed by what you did.

Review your apt logs to see if the release-upgrade encountered problems. Review your syslog and journal to see if the crash was logged, and what clues might be there. Review your /var/crash for .crash files that may have been generated at the time of a crash.

that is not the main problem,
have a look at this question I just posted https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527313/after-upgrading-ubuntu-oh-no-something-went-wrong

Then why is this question open? Perhaps you might consider closing it. Or revising it to ask a question that you want help with.

Did you try sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^?
